# Evaluate in terms of elliptic integral

Tags: definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

Define 
$$f(t):=\int_0^1  \frac{\sqrt{x+t+\sqrt{t^2+2tx+1}}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx $$
Can this integral be evaluated in terms of elliptic integrals? I ask because I have established the functional equation
$$f(t)+f(-t)=2\pi \sqrt{2t}$$
And I hope to turn it into a potentially useful functional equation for elliptic integrals.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that we could find any closed form for this integral and I suppose that you will need numerical integration to get
$$f(t)=\int_0^1  \frac{\sqrt{x+t+\sqrt{t^2+2tx+1}}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, dx$$
On the other hand, I am surprised by
$$f(t)+f(-t)=2\pi \sqrt{2t}$$
Consider $t$ to be small; using Taylor expansions for the integrand and integrating, we have 
$$f(t) =2+t-\frac{t^2}{12}-\frac{t^3}{40}+\frac{5 t^4}{448}+O\left(t^5\right)$$ that is to say
$$f(t)+f(-t)\approx 4-\frac{t^2}{6}+\frac{5 t^4}{224}+O\left(t^6\right)$$ which is "almost" exact for $-1 \leq t \leq 1$.

I produce below a table of numerical values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
t & f(t) & f(-t) & f(t)+f(-t) & 4-\frac{t^2}{6}+\frac{5 t^4}{224}\\
 -3.00 & 0.444240 & 4.25406 & 4.69830 \\
 -2.75 & 0.467638 & 4.10797 & 4.57561 \\
 -2.50 & 0.495114 & 3.95676 & 4.45187 \\
 -2.25 & 0.527996 & 3.79987 & 4.32787 \\
 -2.00 & 0.568309 & 3.63669 & 4.20500 \\
 -1.75 & 0.619341 & 3.46649 & 4.08583 \\
 -1.50 & 0.686924 & 3.28841 & 3.97534 \\
 -1.25 & 0.783061 & 3.10149 & 3.88456 \\
 -1.00 & 0.945822 & 2.90465 & 3.85047 &3.85565\\
 -0.75 & 1.21549 & 2.69676 & 3.91225 &3.91331\\
 -0.50 & 1.48276 & 2.47686 & 3.95962 &3.95973\\
 -0.25 & 1.74522 & 2.24445 & 3.98967 &3.98967\\
 0.00 &  2.00000 & 2.00000 & 4.00000 &4.00000\\
 0.25 &  2.24445 & 1.74522 & 3.98967 &3.98967\\
 0.50 &  2.47686 & 1.48276 & 3.95962 &3.95973\\
 0.75 &  2.69676 & 1.21549 & 3.91225 &3.91331\\
 1.00 &  2.90465 & 0.945822 & 3.85047& 3.85565\\
 1.25 &  3.10149 & 0.783061 & 3.88456 \\
 1.50 & 3.28841 & 0.686924 & 3.97534 \\
 1.75 & 3.46649 & 0.619341 & 4.08583 \\
 2.00 & 3.63669 & 0.568309 & 4.20500 \\
 2.25 & 3.79987 & 0.527996 & 4.32787 \\
 2.50 & 3.95676 & 0.495114 & 4.45187 \\
 2.75 & 4.10797 & 0.467638 & 4.57561 \\
 3.00 & 4.25406 & 0.44424 & 4.69830
\end{array}
\right)$$

If $t$ is large, using Taylor again and integrating

$$f(t)=\frac{\pi 
   \sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t}}-\frac{1}{24 t^2\sqrt{2t}}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^{9/2}}\right)$$ identical to the expansion of the formula given by Mariusz Iwaniuk in his comment.

For $t=10$, the approximation leads to $7.24833$ while the exact value would be $7.24833$ (!!).

Comment: Closed form exist.CAS says: $\frac{\sqrt{2} \pi  \sqrt{t \left(\sqrt{t^2+1}+t\right)}-2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{t \left(\sqrt{t^2+1}+t\right)} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}
   \sqrt{t \left(\sqrt{t^2+1}+t\right)}}\right)+4}{2 \sqrt{\sqrt{t^2+1}+t}}$ for $t>0$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk. This is a good and big surprise to me. Thanks for telling it ! Which CAS did you use ? Cheers.

Comment: Mathematica `11.3`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk. This does not seem to match the numerical results. Being amost blind, I may have made some typo's. Could you check, comparing to numerical integration ? Thanks for letting me know. In any manner, add an answer, please.

Comment: Yours calculation are correct.It seems that: $f(t)+f(-t)\color{red}{\neq} 2 \pi  \sqrt{2 t}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk. Could you send me your formula as an input form for Mathematica. Even if I don't use it, it would easier to read for me. My e-mail address is in my profile. Thanks. By the way, did you check the results ? Cheers.